# Getting rid of unnecessary square brackets in a list

Tags: python, arrays, list, square-bracket

I have a list and I'm trying to append a series of new elements to this list in a certain order: *Day, IDs (Array), Month, Year*. I'm able to add these new elements to the list just fine, however, there are some redundant brackets that show up. Here's an example of the output (see extra []s towards the end of this list):

```
[['Saturday'], array([[1, 2, 5, 3]]), ['August'], [1998], ['Sunday'], array([[7, 1, 3, 4]]), ['May'], [1996], [['Monday'], array([[1, 2, 3, 4]]), ['April'], [1996]], [['Wednesday'], array([[5, 6, 7, 8]]), ['June'], [2001]]]
```

In an attempt to eliminate those, I tried to extend my existing list by accessing the inner list with an index (see line `my_list.extend(temp[0])` below, but doing this does not append the entire`temp` list. The output of this is as follows:

```
[['Saturday'], array([[1, 2, 5, 3]]), ['August'], [1998], ['Sunday'], array([[7, 1, 3, 4]]), ['May'], [1996], ['Monday'], array([[1, 2, 3, 4]]), ['April'], [1996]]
```

The following is a snippet of my code:

```
import numpy as np

my_list = [['Saturday'], np.array([[1,  2,  5, 3]]), ['August'], [1998], ['Sunday'], np.array([[7, 1, 3, 4]]), ['May'], [1996]]

# Note: The lists below could be of any length; not always 2. For example, there could be [['Monday'], ['Tuesday'], ['Wednesday']] and the associated IDs/Months/Years would be of the same length too.

Days = [['Monday'], ['Wednesday']]
IDs = [np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4]]), np.array([[5, 6, 7, 8]])]
Months = [['April'], ['June']]
Years = [[1996], [2001]]

temp = Days, IDs, Months, Years
temp = [list(t) for t in zip(*temp)]
my_list.extend(temp)
print (my_list)
```

How do I eliminate the extra [ ]s so as to achieve my expected output?

Comment: "I'm trying to append a series of new elements to this list in a certain order: Day, IDs (Array), Month, Year. " You need a class. Lists are best used for sequence of homogenous items. When you start storing disparate items that are related in a list, you are entering the land of pain and suffering. Use the appropriate data structure for the job, in this case a dictionary or a class.

Comment: With that said, if you don't want brackets, DON'T PUT THEM IN. For example, `Days = [['Monday'], ['Wednesday']]` explicitly puts in the brackets that you don't want. So remove them.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thanks for your feedback; I'll use your advice

Answer (score 0):

After a few more tries, I finally figured it out. I just flattened my list and it got rid of the redundant square brackets. Here is the updated code:

```
import numpy as np

my_list = [['Saturday'], np.array([[1,  2,  5, 3]]), ['August'], [1998], ['Sunday'], np.array([[7, 1, 3, 4]]), ['May'], [1996]]

Days = [['Monday'], ['Wednesday']]
IDs = [np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4]]), np.array([[5, 6, 7, 8]])]
Months = [['April'], ['June']]
Years = [[1996], [2001]]

temp = Days, IDs, Months, Years
temp = [list(t) for t in zip(*temp)]
my_list.extend(temp)
flat_list = [item for sublist in my_list for item in sublist]
print (flat_list)
```

Output:

```
['Saturday', array([1, 2, 5, 3]), 'August', 1998, 'Sunday', array([7, 1, 3, 4]), 'May', 1996, ['Monday'], array([[1, 2, 3, 4]]), ['April'], [1996], ['Wednesday'], array([[5, 6, 7, 8]]), ['June'], [2001]]
```